# Have a problem when used route to controller with variable

Tags: laravel-5

I used Laravel route as follow.

```
    Route::get('report/centos7/{id}', 'HomeController@centos7');
```

And then in Controller, I used this code to return View.

```
    \View::make('report/centos7/', $id);
```

An error occurred as follow.

```
    InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
    View [report.centos7.] not found.
```

I called the URL like this "mysite/laravelproject/public/report/centos7/result_target2"

I using Laravel 5.2
First time I used this code in Controller
        return \View::make('report/centos7/'. $id);
But, the CSS and JS is not loaded. I think because of "."
That is why I changed from "." to ","

Route

```
Route::get('report/centos7/{id}', 'HomeController@centos7');
```

HomeController

```
public function centos7($id)
{
    //
    return \View::make('report/centos7', $id);
}
```

I had dynamically added "blade.php" into folder view/report/centos7/xxxx.blade.php
I created a new page to list all files in that folder and link each of the files to show the report in blade format.
I hope Laravel route to Controller is can help to access my report in blade format
Thanks for help. I'm a newbie in programming language

**Update**

I removed {id} in route as follow

```
Route::get('report/centos7/{id}', 'HomeController@centos7');
```

To

```
Route::get('report/centos7/', 'HomeController@centos7');
```

And removed id in HomeController as well
It works. But, I still want to send $id from Route to HomeController
When I do that I don't know why CSS is not loaded in my blade php.
Please help.

**Update (Sovled)**

Thank god everyone
If anyone has the same problem as me
I changed my href into the layout as follow and it works.

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('theme/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the extra `/` in your view code:

```
\View::make('report/centos7/', $id);
```

If you change it to the following, it should all work correctly:

```
\View::make('report.centos7', $id);
```

Make sure that your HTML code is in the `resources/views/report/centos7.blade.php` file.